# ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, opencv

Tengo un proyecto en python con librerías instaladas dentro de un env.

Al ejecutar el script que quiero ejecutar me sale el siguiente error:

> ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.

Según entiendo debo de ser root para poderlo ejecutar, pero no entiendo cómo ejecutar el script como root dentro de un env.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de ejecutar el env, ejecuta el comando `sudo su`, te pedira la contraseña, una vez la introduzcas te convertiras en root dentro de ese terminal.
Otra opcion es cambiarle los permisos a la libreria en cuestion ya sea mediante entorno grafico o por terminal `chmod 755 nombrelibreria`

Comment: Funciona, gracias!

Comment: De nada, cuando una respuesta sea lo que buscas debes de marcar el tick que hay a la izquierda de la misma. además evita los comentarios  de "gracias" ya que no están bien vistos en SO.